# Google Translate API logging permission denied

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, google-cloud-platform, google-translate

I am using the Google Translate API v2 and I am able to get the translations but I also get these errors on the side which I am not able to resolve.

```
Failed to submit 1 logs.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 67, in error_remapped_callable
    return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 946, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 849, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _InactiveRpcError(state)
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
        status = StatusCode.PERMISSION_DENIED
        details = "Permission 'logging.logEntries.create' denied on resource (or it may not exist)."
        debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1659523475.735415900","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:142.250.194.234:443","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":966,"grpc_message":"Permission 'logging.logEntries.create' denied on resource (or it may not exist).","grpc_status":7}"
>

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/logging_v2/handlers/transports/background_thread.py", line 114, in _safely_commit_batch
    batch.commit()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/logging_v2/logger.py", line 385, in commit
    client.logging_api.write_entries(entries, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/logging_v2/_gapic.py", line 149, in write_entries
    self._gapic_api.write_log_entries(request=request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/logging_v2/services/logging_service_v2/client.py", line 615, in write_log_entries
    metadata=metadata,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py", line 145, in __call__
    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 291, in retry_wrapped_func
    on_error=on_error,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 189, in retry_target
    return target()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 69, in error_remapped_callable
    six.raise_from(exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc), exc)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 Permission 'logging.logEntries.create' denied on resource (or it may not exist).
Failed to submit 1 logs.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 67, in error_remapped_callable
    return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 946, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 849, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _InactiveRpcError(state)
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
        status = StatusCode.PERMISSION_DENIED
        details = "Permission 'logging.logEntries.create' denied on resource (or it may not exist)."
        debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1659523476.318220100","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:142.250.194.234:443","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":966,"grpc_message":"Permission 'logging.logEntries.create' denied on resource (or it may not exist).","grpc_status":7}"
>

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/logging_v2/handlers/transports/background_thread.py", line 114, in _safely_commit_batch
    batch.commit()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/logging_v2/logger.py", line 385, in commit
    client.logging_api.write_entries(entries, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/logging_v2/_gapic.py", line 149, in write_entries
    self._gapic_api.write_log_entries(request=request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/logging_v2/services/logging_service_v2/client.py", line 615, in write_log_entries
    metadata=metadata,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py", line 145, in __call__
    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 291, in retry_wrapped_func
    on_error=on_error,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 189, in retry_target
    return target()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 69, in error_remapped_callable
    six.raise_from(exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc), exc)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 Permission 'logging.logEntries.create' denied on resource (or it may not exist).
```

I am guesing that this issue is because of the logging but I am not able to turn off the logging. I used the following reference - https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/basic/translating-text#translating_text and the Python code mentioned here.

I am writing the code inside Django.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Python client is attempting to write in Google Cloud log.

Either this is a feature / setting in your client (that you might want to disable), or you might want to add the permission to your API keys to allow the API key to write in Google Cloud Log

[image]